# python send email global name 'msg' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code snippet to send an email in Python.  I am getting the error NameError: global name 'msg' is not defined:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests/selenium_regression_test_5_1_1/Email/email_selenium_report.py", line 32, in <module>
    report.send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report()
  File "E:\test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Email\report.py", line 516, in send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report
    msg['Subject'] = "ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test"
NameError: global name 'msg' is not defined
```

My code is:

```
def send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report():
    print extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
    print extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
    all_testcases = list(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner())
    # print all_data
    pprint.pprint(all_testcases)


    msg['Subject'] = "ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test"
    msg['body'] = "\n ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test_IE11_Selenium_VM   \n " + extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() + "\n extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() \n" + list(
        extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) + "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n"

    msg['to'] = "cc4_server_dev@company.onmicrosoft.com", "riazladhani@company.com"
    msg['From'] = "system@company.com"

    s = smtplib.SMTP()
    s.connect(host=SMTP_SERVER)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg['body'], msg.as_string())
    s.close()


def extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    #Create list here...
    results = []

    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
#    print(" ".join(headers))

    #Don't forget to append header (if you want)
    results.append(headers)
    return results

def extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    #Create list here...
    results = []
    for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
        #Store row string in variable and append before printing
        row_str = " ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]])
        results.append(row_str)
#        print(row_str)

    return results


def extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    for div in soup.select("#result_table tr div.testcase"):
          yield div.text.strip().encode('utf-8'), div.find_next("a").text.strip().encode('utf-8')
```

How do I solve this error?
I tried to put msg = MIMEText(text, "html") above the msg['Subject']  It does not like that.

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: _It does not like that_ it's not a precise problem statement. You are trying to set some values on `msg` object, but this object is not created anywhere. You need to create a container  for your message (`MIMEText `, `MIMEMultipart` etc. - depending on what exactly you need). If you have problem with exactly that, most of code in question is not needed. Learn more about creating [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare `msg` variable inside `send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report` function.
You can do it e.g. like this:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msg = MIMEText('body of your message')
```

Comment: I get the error: msg = MIMEText()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: ahh, you can pass some payload as the first argument

Answer (score 0):

Including this code might rectify your issue:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg=MIMEMultipart()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score -1):

it seems like you haven't declared your variable `msg` correctly.
I assume you declare it somewhere off the code we're seeing here.
but make sure you assign some value to it, even None, in this case though it should be `MIMEText(content, "html")` for example.
as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297548/2860157).

if that doesn't help please post the new exception you're getting even after you define `msg`